# Windows 8 Metro UI App using JAVA

Tags: java, windows-8

How to create a Windows 8 desktop application using JAVA as a source language ?

Please tell me what tools I can use for the same ?

I have done a lot of research but I cannot find a way to get out of the problem. Please help me out.

Thanks in advance.

And please instead of down vote this, please try to help me if you can.

Take care!

Comment: `I have done a lot of research but I cannot find a way to get out of the problem` Would you mind to share your research, telling us what you found and why it can't be done? That way we can better understand your issue and try to help you out

Comment: Well, I found that Visual Studio has support for JAVA also, but I am not into C# or ASP,so I cannot say anything for Visual Studio.. Oracle says - "Windows 8 don't allow JAVA to run on start screen but on desktop screen". Some says - "It's not possible". So, I am confused !

Comment: In this article, [Creating Your First Windows 8 Modern UI / Metro App](http://www.mikemarks.net/blog/creating-windows-8-metro-app/), Java is **not** mentioned as one of the development language options.

Comment: This article says there is a 3rd party SDK: http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2012/09/12/write-windows-8-apps-in-native-java.aspx (its almost the first google hit...)

Comment: @Gilbert.. Well I saw this link, but according to the Oracle standard, you can link JAVA through Visual Studio via a plugin. I am novice to VS so I am confused and need to know if someone has done anything using JAVA and, if yes, then how .. Thanks for your revert

Comment: @Durandal Yes, I saw this link also, but I didn't find it impressive. Anyways, thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use Java for developing Windows Store apps (aka Metro UI apps).

See here: https://dev.windows.com/en-us/getstarted
"You can write a Windows Runtime app in a variety of languages, such as C# or C++ with XAML, C++ with DirectX, and JavaScript with HTML/CSS."